# Apache rewrite condition get second regex match

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I''m sorry for asking the millionth Apache rewrite question here. I tried everything I know, but there is a small (hopefully) step that I'm looking for someone to shed a light for me.

I have a URL structure similar to this:

```
 - assets
 - assets/dist/19854/css/my.css
 - css/my.css
```

I'm trying to rewrite `assets/dist/19854/css/my.css file` to `css/my.css` file in the root.

I have mod_rewrite enabled on my server, and I have basic understanding of rewrite rules, but it would be great if you could assist me with the Regex.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^assets/dist/([0-9/.]+)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^assets/dist/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ $ [L,QSA]
```

Problem with the above rule is the it rewrite to `./19854`, but I'm actually interested in the second expression's match. If possible, I'd also like to make sure the `css/my.css` file exists first.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Thanks for the comments and the answer. To further explain my case, this is a small site that uses a CDN, and everytime a new build is up, the number in assets/dist/[0-9] gets changed, so all assets' source URL gets changed. But I'm using a CSS compiler to compile CSS files, so CSS files reside in the same folder (`css/my.css`). 
I have some other rewrites so I'm making my `RewriteCond`s more strict.

So far, the above rewrite matches the numeric part, but I'm trying to rewrite to the URL right after the numeric part.

[image: current match]

Comment: References in `RewriteRule`'s can be referenced with $1, $2, etc., references in `RewriteCond`'s can be referened with %1, %2, %3, etc. Why do you havea rewritecond exactly matching your rule BTW?

Comment: I had to use a strict RewriteCond because there are some other rewrites, and this rewrite only matches a small portion of the site. 
I tried to use $1, 2, etc but they all give the same result (in a real server as well. The screenshot above is from http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: That tester is broken. Use `$2` and test on a real server.

Comment: You sir is a lifesaver! I had a problem in my `RewriteCond` that prevented the rewrite from running in my server and for the whole time, I was struggling with $1, 2 and %s. I didn't honestly know the difference between % and $. Thanks a lot for the wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're attempting in other way round. You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# route to /css/my.css if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/dist/.+?/(css/my\.css)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, @anubhava, but I'm sorry I am looking for a slightly different one. Could you see the screenshot in my new question edit? My `RewriteRule` matches the first regex's match but I'm trying to rewrite to the second regex's.

Comment: I had understood your requirement of using CDN even before your edit. You don't need `RewriteCond` here. Even if you use it must be: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/dist/([0-9/.]+)/(.*)$` with a leading slash. But as I showed in my answer you don't need need it.

Comment: You are right it was actually the bad rewrite condition that messed up my testing. This one looks more cleaner as well. Thanks for your answer, that is much appreciated.